# htaccess redirect exception folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am needing to forward a whole domain minus one folder and it's contents.

http://www.domain.com/folder_I_need/content_I_need.stuff

The rest of the site needs to forward.

Here is what I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder_I_need/$
Redirect 301 / http://www.new_domain.org/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RewriteCond` directive is part of mod_rewrite and `Redirect` directive part of mod_alias, they don't work in conjunction with each other. You also probably don't want the `$` at the end of your condition's pattern. Try:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder_I_need/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new_domain.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That isn't working. It is still forwarding the full URL to the new domain. Like this:   `http://www.old-domain.com/folder_I_need/file_I'm_liking to` forwards to `http://www.new_domain.org/folder_I_need/file_I'm_liking to`.

Comment: This does work as long as I don't put in the www in the old domain url. Thanks!